# Promise in JavaScript (angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube-api

I'm quite new to angular and http calls.

Then i read something about Promise to aync calls. And i cannot understand it at all. 
So i need some help to know if im even going the right direction.

I'm programming an API for getting Videoes, and details about them (Views etc) with Youtube API v3.

But i seem to get an error with the getting the details since my array is empty all the time.

```
    /*var promises = [];*/ // PROMISE
                var videometrics;
                var videodetails = [];
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=' + playlistId + '&key=AIzaSyDQv-WpATIWLinCB3H_sH4W1sKx7plyvRA')
                    .success(function (response) {

                        for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
                            var video = {
                                id: response.items[i].snippet.resourceId.videoId,
                                title: response.items[i].snippet.title
                            };
                            $scope.video.push(video)


                        }
                        /*console.log($scope.video)
                        var promises = [];*/
                        for (i = 0; i < $scope.video.length; i++) {
                            /*console.log("looping")
                            console.log($scope.video)
                            console.log("Vi henter fra id:")
                            console.log($scope.video[i].id)*/
                            $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=' + $scope.video[i].id + '&key=AIzaSyDQv-WpATIWLinCB3H_sH4W1sKx7plyvRA')
                                .success(function (responsevideo) {
                                    /*console.log($scope.video[i].id);*/

                                    //                                console.log("we are in the metric loop")
                                    //                                console.log($scope.video[i].id)
                                    //                                console.log($scope.video[i].title)
                                    //                                console.log(responsevideo)
                                        videometrics = {
                                            id: responsevideo.items[0].id,
                                            views: responsevideo.items[0].statistics.viewCount,
                                            likes: responsevideo.items[0].statistics.likeCount,
                                            dislikes: responsevideo.items[0].statistics.dislikeCount,
                                            favorites: responsevideo.items[0].statistics.favoriteCount,
                                            comments: responsevideo.items[0].statistics.commentCount
                                        };
                                    videodetails.push(videometrics);
                                    deferred.resolve(responsevideo);
                                    /*detailsOnVideos = $scope.videometrics;*/

                                })
                           /* videodetails.push(videometrics);*/
                        }
                        /*promises.push(videodetails);*/ // PROMISE

                        console.log(videodetails);
                       /* console.log(promises);*/ //PROMISE LOGGER
 /*                       console.log(videodetails);*/
                        console.log($scope.video);
                        console.log("")
                        pagetokenarr = response.nextPageToken;
                        console.log(pagetokenarr)

                    });
                return deferred;
                /*return $q.all(promises);*/ // PROMISE
```

as you see my first http get, is functionel, but the next one is not. And i cant understand why. But if i push my videodetails array into a promise array it works. And again. I donno why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution working in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IgISsres5OlugrUCpa41?p=preview)

Your code was pretty much working. The problem was that your `console.log()` was fired too early because it wasn't in a `.success()` or `.then()` of your promises. It was fired before the `$http` calls resolved.

I reworked a bit your code (specially theses `for` loops) to make it more readable.

Also you don't need to build your own promises till `$http` calls return promises

Here is the final code :

```
$http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=' + playlistId + '&key=AIzaSyDQv-WpATIWLinCB3H_sH4W1sKx7plyvRA')
    .success(function (response) {
        angular.forEach(response.items, function(item){
            var video = {
                  id: item.snippet.resourceId.videoId,
                  title: item.snippet.title
            };  
            $scope.video.push(video);
        }) 
        console.log($scope.video);
        angular.forEach($scope.video, function(video){
          httpcalls.push($http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=' + video.id + '&key=AIzaSyDQv-WpATIWLinCB3H_sH4W1sKx7plyvRA')
                .success(function (responsevideo) {
                  videometrics = {
                            id: responsevideo.items[0].id,
                            views: responsevideo.items[0].statistics.viewCount,
                            likes: responsevideo.items[0].statistics.likeCount,
                            dislikes: responsevideo.items[0].statistics.dislikeCount,
                            favorites: responsevideo.items[0].statistics.favoriteCount,
                            comments: responsevideo.items[0].statistics.commentCount
                        };
                    $scope.videodetails.push(videometrics);
                }));
        });
        pagetokenarr = response.nextPageToken;
        $q.all(httpcalls).then(function(){
          console.log($scope.videodetails);
        }) 

    });
```

Note that i push all the `$http` call into a collection (`httpcalls`) and wrap your console.log into a `$q.all(httpcalls).then()` function. This will wait until all the `$http` calls into the collection are resolved.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks alot! I've tried alot with those forEach (first time i tried them), and now i know how they work aswell. I see the point you're making about the console.log where executed before the http calls. Perfect!

Comment: My post explain why it wasn't working and give a workaround. But for a cleaner way of doing your $http calls (into services) keep in mind the @Sphaso answer

Answer (score 2):

You don't need $q with $http. There's basically two ways (that I know of) to work with $http:

1) make a service, isolate $http there. Return the promise as such:

```
return $http.get({params...}).then(function(data) {
     return data.result;
 });
```

then in the controller you'd have:

```
SuperService.get(params...).then(function(data) { $scope.something = data; });
```

2) databinding! make a service, put the $http in there. But this time you bind the result to an object inside the service. In the service you also have a method to return that object.

```
$http.get({params...}).then(function(data) {
     myObject = data.result;
 });
```

Then in the controller:

```
$scope.spiderman = SuperService.getObj();
SuperService.get(params...);
```

When you call .get() AngularJS does its magic and updates $scope.spiderman (as soon as you get a response from the server, of course).

Relevant literature:

- [ngDocs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)
- ["We have a problem with promises" by Lawson](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html)

Comment: It actually don't explain why the OP code wasn't working, but this is still pretty much the best practices about this.

Comment: You're right, but I don't want to encourage bad practices.

Comment: Totally agree, that's why you got my upvote. Pointing out the OP trouble with his $console.log would have made it a perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to working fine. I have removed all but the essentials, added the variables that I needed as placeholders as I'm not sure of the playlistId etc. Here is the code that I have tested.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []); 
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
var videometrics;
$scope.videodetails = [];
var playlistId = "PL63F0C78739B09958";
$scope.video = [];
$http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=' + playlistId + '&key=AIzaSyDQv-WpATIWLinCB3H_sH4W1sKx7plyvRA')
    .success(function (response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
            var video = {
                id: response.items[i].snippet.resourceId.videoId,
                title: response.items[i].snippet.title
            };
            $scope.video.push(video);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.video.length; i++) {
            $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=' + $scope.video[i].id + '&key=AIzaSyDQv-WpATIWLinCB3H_sH4W1sKx7plyvRA')
            .success(function (responsevideo) {
                var videometrics = {
                    id: responsevideo.items[0].id,
                    views: responsevideo.items[0].statistics.viewCount,
                    likes: responsevideo.items[0].statistics.likeCount,
                    dislikes: responsevideo.items[0].statistics.dislikeCount,
                    favorites: responsevideo.items[0].statistics.favoriteCount,
                    comments: responsevideo.items[0].statistics.commentCount
                };
                $scope.videodetails.push(videometrics);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This will display in the browser using {{videodetails}} when it available on the scope.

If you need to work with the data as opposed to merely displaying it you will likely need to use a service as the other answer suggests.

Comment: The problem here is that the second for loop, i need to get specific metrics. when im saving those data in an array, the array just seems empty.

Comment: I've edited my answer above so that it will display all of the specific metrics.